# how to copy float32 value to uint64 container using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to write any given value in `temp` to float32, and then store this float value in `uint64` container.

```
value =  np.array(temp, dtype=np.float32, ndmin=1) //works fine
data_f_value = np.frombuffer(value, dtype='uint64') //ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size
```

I get ValueError and it's expected, but how we can do this operation using numpy ?

Comment: why not use `value.astype("uint64")`?

Comment: No.. this will just convert the value to uint64.. But this is not what I want.. So for example value float32 2.0 to be represented into uint64 format

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  "store a float value in `uint64`" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you're looking for a [view](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html). Example with the value `0.15625` from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32):

```
import numpy as np
value =  np.array([0.15625], dtype=np.float32)
data_f_value = value.view(np.uint32).astype(np.uint64)
#array([1042284544], dtype=uint64)
print(' '.join(f'{x:016b}' for x in  value.tobytes()))
print(' '.join(f'{x:016b}' for x in  data_f_value.tobytes()))
```

Output:

```
0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000100000 0000000000111110
0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000100000 0000000000111110 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
```

As the name suggests, this returns a view. If you want to copy as per your question title you'd need `value.view(np.uint32).astype(np.uint64).copy()`.

Comment: Yes.. even my code does that.. but problem is that float32 is 4bytes and uint64 is f 8 bytre.. view also raise similar issue `ValueError: When changing to a larger dtype, its size must be a divisor of the total size in bytes of the last axis of the array.`

Comment: if you want to convert 4 bytes to 8 bytes you'll have to prepend or append zeros, depending on endianness. I've updated my anser for this case.